# Can't get location without wifi

Tags: android, location

Whatever I do, I just can't get current location without wifi enabled. This code works only when wifi is enabled:

```
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER))
    provider = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

When wifi is disabled, `location` is null.

And the following code never works (even if wifi is enabled):

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

in `onCreate()`:

```
buildGoogleApiClient();
```

in `onStart()`:

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

And here's `onConnected()`:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(mLastLocation == null)
    {
        disableButtons();
    }
    else
    {
        String userLocation = FindLocation.getLocatoinName(mLastLocation);
        userLocationDetails = new LocationStruct(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), userLocation);
    }
}
```

Inside `onConnected()`, `mLastLocation` is always null.

I tried on 2 phones: **Lenovo A820 API 16** and **Samsung Galaxy S4 API 19**. Same result on both phones.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on Last Known Location to always be available.
In your `onConnected()` you're only checking for the last known location.

You have to create a `LocationRequest` in your `onConnected()`

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(locationPriority) // LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 * 1000 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
```

Then you have to request location updates:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

You'll then get Location in `onLocationChanged(Location location)`

Comment: @Alaa M. Can you post your entire activity in which you're try this?